# Java MySQL connector not detected in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classpath

I am writing an SQL syntax helper to automate some things. I can not get the MySQL connector to be detected.

I have added mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar to my build path, and they both show in my referenced libraries.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       

    getCredentials();
    login();

    while(run)
    {

        String input = getInput("Please enter the query: ");

        String[] arguments = input.split(" ");
        System.out.println(arguments);
        switch(arguments[0])
        {
            case "":
                ;
                break;
            case "exit":
                run = false;
                break;
        }

    }
    scan.close();
}

public static void login()
{
    try
    {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         connect = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(
                 "jdbc:mysql://%suser=%s&password=%s", DATA_BASE, username, password 
         ));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        print(e.toString());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

When run, it gives the following error.

```
C:\Users\""\workspace\SQLParser\bin>java SQLParser
Enter your username:
Enter your password:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

C:\Users\""\workspace\SQLParser\bin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it as `java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar SQLParser`

Also, make sure `mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar` is present in `C:\Users\""\workspace\SQLParser\bin`

**Update:**

Based on your comment, the following will be applicable in your case:

```
C:\Users\your-user-name\workspace\SQLParser\bin>java -cp ".;../lib/*" your.package.SQLParser
```

Replace `your-user-name` and `your.package` with actual values.

Comment: `C:\Users\""\workspace\SQLParser\bin>java domain."".SQLParser
Enter your username:
Enter your password:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver



C:\Users\""\workspace\SQLParser\bin>java -cp ..\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar;..\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar domain."".SQLParser
Error: Could not find or load main class domain."".SQLParser



C:\Users\""\workspace\SQLParser\bin>`

Comment: [Connectors](https://i.imgur.com/5va9MAj.png)
[Class](https://i.imgur.com/txN1JSX.png)

Comment: I can run from Eclipse without this error occurring, but then I can not use `console#readPassword`. Theres got to be something more than using -cp <lib_path> ...

Comment: I got it. I can run using -cp if I also specify the `bin` directory.